# doctrine - How to update all rows but one by ID

Tags: php, doctrine

There's `isDefault` property in an entity. If it's set to true, the `isDefault` property of all other entities must be set to `false`.

Is there a clean solution without the QueryBuilder or plain SQL? And if so, what is the solution.

TLDR: How can I update one ore more values of any entity whose ID IS NOT a specific one?

**Update**

I have a table of entities. Only one entity can have a `(bool) isDefault` status. If I create a new entity, which can be set to `isDefault = true` all other entities must be set to `isDefault = false`.

Comment: why is QueryBuilder "not clean"?

Comment: `...  WHERE id <> 5` ?

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-equal-operator.php

Comment: I didn't say QueryBuilder or plain SQL is not clean. I'm looking for a possible solution without them which is also clean.

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly. And more specific details are required

Comment: There's not really a "clean" way of doing this purely with the ORM because the application only knows what is actively managed, which risks an invalid entity state or race condition when persisting a single entity, and performance issues when loading all entities. One approach is to setup an event to monitor the state change of before and after changing the `isDefault` property, then execute an update query when it is changed from `false` to `true`. Would need to have more details on how the relationships are setup and how you plan to maintain the `isDefault` to elaborate more.

Comment: These are the ones that scare me when I abstract things away to an ORM. I just ran across this with a recent project and almost decided to try creating an additional property of `defaultThing` in addition to `things`. The latter would have the standard OneToMany but the former would be a OneToOne. My reasoning was that the individual "things" don't have a concept of "default", it is the entity that _holds_ it that cares. Ultimately I didn't do this, and just did a `for` loop when updating, setting everything else to `false` except the selected one.

Comment: To expand upon my earlier comment, depending on the context of `isDefault` and what it applies to, its usage generally points to a relation on another entity. For example `Account::$contacts[]->isDefault`.  Instead of using a `Contact::$isDefault` property that would need to be filtered in subqueries and `WHERE` criteria to retrieve, a `ManyToOne` relationship for  `Account::$defaultContact` could be used instead. This alleviates the need to track the value of the column, the need to manage special criteria or functions to handle them and can then be managed from the relational context.

Comment: @WillB. No it doesn't point to a relation to another entity. This case is as simple as described above and showed in my solution below. The real life scenario is a collection of VAT entities. Only one VAT can be the default for any list where they're used. Like invoice forms, selling forms, etc. And that single VAT entity is the default selected in e. g. a drop down. In fact in germany there're always 2 active VATs at the same time while one of them is the most used. The second one is for a very small amount of goods.

Comment: @codekandis you misunderstood my meaning. The usage of `default` in general means in preference to a specific subject matter, such as `Country::$defaultVAT` as in your given example. In your context it may not actually have a relation but doesn't mean that one is not implied.

Comment: @WillB. I understand your approach now. But in programming I experienced based on "Read Like Speak" that `isSomething` implies the mentioned entity / object is in fact that "something" - represented by a boolean flag. If you have two entities of the same type with `isDefault = true` - default means the one and only. But to come to a conclusion: In the case of my example it has been shown that the understanding of language and its particular meaning differs alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not to update all other entities whose state can already be `isDefault = false` but to update only those which have the state `isDefault = true`.

```php
$entities = $entityManager->getRepository( Entity::class )
    ->findBy(
        [
            'isDefault' => true
        ]
    );
foreach( $entities as $entity )
{
    $entity->setIsDefault( false );
}

$newEntity = new Entity();
$newEntity->setIsDefault( true );
$entityManager->persist( $newEntity );

$entityManager->flush();
```

It would be possible to use `findOneBy()` but this is the more safe approach to prevent multiple entities with the same `isDefault = true` status.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the relation to cascade-all and then use setters with persist to persist updates.
Read [Doctrine: Transitive persistence / Cascade Operation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) for more info.

```php
class Entity {

  #[Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
  protected bool $isDefault;

  #[OneToMany(..., cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
  protected Collection $children;


  public function setIsDefault(bool $isDefault) {
    $this->isDefault = true;
    foreach ($this->children as $child) {
      $child->setIsDefault($isDefault);
    }
  }
}

// In your code:
$entity->setIsDefault(true);
$entityManger->persist($entity);
$entity->flush();
```

Comment: Would suggest excluding the argument from the entity method, as something like `Entity::applyDefault();` and forcing `$child->setIsDefault(false);`, otherwise `Entity::setIsDefault(true)` would apply `true` to all the `Entity::$children`, however the current example looks to cause an infinite loop.